# Windows Phone 7 - Make a call without user notification

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

Is there any way from which i can call to any phone number from my contact list without showing user a notification?

Comment: I would love to know why you want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

No, that capability is not in the Windows Phone API. (And it's a good thing, IMO. Why would you legitimately need this ?).

Comment: I want to make an application which will send user multiple message and dial a number on its birthday and play a custom song or voice. This currently cannot be done without user interference i.e. user actually clicking on dial button. So i want to make this in background. Windows currently does not expose any api to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Despite the popular misconception that this is completely impossible on Windows Phone, I must say that it **is possible**, but with a bit more work than you would expect. The key here are AT commands - the `ATD` command, to be specific (most [Motorola commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_phone_AT_commands) work as well).

Windows Phone devices offer you access to AT commands through native libraries shipped as a part of the OS or as a part of OEM applications.

So to say, you find yourself behind these barriers:

1. Your application will not get approved in the Marketplace. This means that the user has to sideload it, and not a lot of non-devs will be comfortable with performing this operation.
2. Since a lot of devices are now becoming Mango-phones (updated to Windows Phone OS 7.5), you will not be able to invoke system interop calls from within a non-signed third-party application. That leaves you with a NoDo requirement at least to install the application.

I worked with similar stuff on a Dell Venue Pro to send SMS messages and [was quite successful with it](http://dennisdel.com/?p=863). But it's not officially supported, so that cuts it.

Comment: Here you are talking mostly about phone other then Windows Phone 7. I was not able to find a way to do that. Kindly share the code to access AT command

Comment: You will have to look for that on your own, depending on the model of your device.

Comment: @Dennis Delimarsky: Would you mind providing a source for your second point? I've tried googling for about 10 minutes about the system calls from non signed third party assemblies related to the mango update, but I couldn't find anything. By "signed" you mean "signed" by Microsoft, I guess?