# Making a phone call in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing a Windows Phone app, which needs to make an automatic call when some event occurs, without user interference. Is it possible? (Purpose is legitimate)

If not, is there any other way to send some notification or message to the other phone from my windows phone app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 - Make a call without user notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338569/windows-phone-7-make-a-call-without-user-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a [PhoneCallTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on Mango or later (so SDK 7.1 and later) - this can be pre-filled, but the action to place the call must be completed by the user of the phone.

Similarly, SMS messaging also requires confirmation (after all, both these actions cost money) - if you need inter-phone communication, you could implement yourself via a webservice and push notifications.

Comment: I think Push-notification needs both the phones to be Windows phones. What if the other phone is an Android device or iPhone?

Comment: ...then you implement a client for those platforms, and abstract the push notifications so that it works for your supported platforms. either that, or accept that the user has to connect the call (after all, you can pre-fill the number/display name)

Comment: Any 3rd party API like skype is available to make a call for windows phone?

Comment: There is a Skype client, but I wouldn't know without using my local, friendly search engine, whether they've exposed an API for Windows Phone developers.

Comment: As aside, it seems thoroughly evil to place a call without the user's consent, and I'd avoid installing any application that did that.

Comment: As a second aside, [somebody else has already asked about using Skype](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10720942/50447) from another Windows Phone app

Answer (score 1):

The only way for apps to make a phone call is by using [`PhoneCallTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which requires user interaction, so I'm afraid you're out of luck.