# call skype user from my Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone appllication I need to realize skype call to some users. Is it possible to call skype user from my Windows Phone application?

Comment: Maybe not yours... I mean, Skype already has a Windows Phone application. They did, however, removed the app from the marketplace for Lumia 610 users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for this and no public SDK specifically for Windows Phone.

If you really must do this then you'll need to implement a WP7 compatible interface to [their API](http://developer.skype.com/public-api-reference).