# Windows Phone 8 - Make a call without user notification

Tags: windows-phone-8, at-command

Is there any way a Windows Phone 8 app can make phone calls, sending SMS, and perform other cellular network activities without user interaction?

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7342769 it is somehow possible to perform AT commands to directly access the cellular functionality on Windows Phone 7 (in an inofficial way). Since the Windows Phone 8 SDK supports native code, my question is if you can make use of this to send the required AT commands or access the RIL layer somehow.

In case anyone is wondering why I need this: it's not about an app wich is going to get published but it is needed for an automated testing process.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, this is not possible in windows phone

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).